# Why am I unable to execute command as another user in CentOs?

Tags: centos, bash, sudo, centos6.5

On a remote server, it used to be the case that it was possible to execute a command as another user using the **sudo -u**  command but lately, I have been unable to accomplish this. When I do I receive the following error:

```
sudo -u lool ./autogen.sh 
/var/tmp/scltjLjKc: line 8: -u: command not found
```

so I'm having to resort sudo-ing to root then su into the user before being able to execute the command. What could be the possible cause of this?

Comment: add your user into sudoer: run visudo

Comment: Do a `which sudo`, what is the path of the sudo binary you are running?  What is the contents of that file `/var/tmp/scltjLjKc`?  What you are showing us is unusual, I have never seen output like that  before from sudo.

Comment: BTW, have you seen these?  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1319936 http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192809/sudo-i-returns-an-error?  Those seem to show that having the package `devtoolset` installed gives you a crappy sudo wrapper that breaks things.

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks. I'll use the link to look into the issue in a day or so.

Answer (score 2):

Since this never got an answer, the comment by Zoredache is correct. Installing one of the `devtoolset-*` software collections is responsible for this problem. I can't imagine who thought hijacking `sudo` was a reasonable or responsible thing to do.

The quickest way to resolve it, without messing with your path and possibly breaking the development tools you've just installed is to do this:

```
# alter the file, so that it won't get overwritten by updates
echo '### garbage ####' >> /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/sudo
# make it non-executable so your system won't try to run it
chmod -x /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/sudo
```

Of course, replace `devtoolset-2` with whatever version you're using.